# Can sharing be set up between Accounts with Customer Community Plus licenses?

Tags: community

I am setting two communities using Customer Community Plus licenses. The first community is just for "members", and when they community user logs in they should only be able to see their own records (a bunch of custom objects I built). I haven't done this yet, but I assume when I set my OWD to Private, then this will limit what each user sees to their own records. (Right now they can login and see all records owned by anyone on the tabs they have access to). So first I wanted to confirm that setting OWD to private will have the desired result.

Secondly, after I set OWD to Private I will create another community using the same CC+ licenses. But in this community I want "Team Leaders" to be able to have access to records owned by other users who will have different Accounts. I am using NPSP, so each individual user will have their own Household Account, but I need the Team Leader to be able to sign in and have access to all records associated with the Program Site Custom object that I built. The records they will need access to will be owned by people with different accounts, but will be in a related list through a lookup field on the Program Site custom object. Can someone let me know if this is possible. Everything I can find online says if I use roles and hierarchies it only opens up records within the same Account...but I need access across Accounts. Thank you for your help!

Comment: With the second requirement I wonder if there is a way of doing this with Public Groups as roles based sharing will not work.

Answer (score 0):

your first assumption is correct, you just need to use Org Wide Sharing to private.

If I'm understanding you second scenario correctly I believe you should be able to use Sharing Sets to give your team leaders access to those Program Site custom objects:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customer_portal_sharing_set.htm&language=en_US

I believe their example summarizes what you are looking for:

> Grant users access to all cases(Program Site) related to a parent account or contact
>   that is identified on the user’s(Team Leader) account or contact record.

Comment: Actually that is incorrect about Sharing Sets - they can be used with Customer Community and Customer Community Login licences, not Customer Community Plus licences.